# Using seq() and ifelse in a for loop

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, seq

I'm trying to make the following "sequence":

```
0.0025,0.005, 0.010, 0.015, 0.020, 0.025, 0.030, 0.035, 0.040, 0.045, 0.050, 0.055, 0.060
```

As you can see, after the first value 0.0025, the values increase by 0.0025 and then continuously by 0.005. So after the second value of 0.005, it is essentially a sequence increasing by 0.005. Which I thought I could use seq() in.

What I thought would work would be:

```
    matrix1 <- matrix("", nrow = 1, ncol = 13)
    m <-  for (i in 1:length(matrix1){

    matrix1[,i] <- ifelse(i == 1, 0.0025, ifelse(i == 2, 0.005, seq(0.01,    0.05, by = 0.005)))
}
```

This however gives me the following result:

```
     [,1]     [,2]    [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10]  [,11]  [,12]  [,13] 
[1,] "0.0025" "0.005" "0.01" "0.01" "0.01" "0.01" "0.01" "0.01" "0.01" "0.01" "0.01" "0.01" "0.01"
```

Which is not what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `c(0.0025, seq(0.005, 0.06, by=0.005))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is really about using a `for` loop, then I'd rather use `if` and `else` statements:

```
n <- 13
x1 <- vector("numeric", 13)
for (i in 1:n) {
  if (i==1) {
    x1[i] <- 0.0025
  } else {
    x1[i] <- 0.005 + (i-2)*0.005
  }
}
```

... because `ifelse` is meant to be applied on vectors :

```
j <- 1:n
x2 <- ifelse(j == 1, 0.0025, 0.005 + (j-2)*0.005)
```

But there are so many other ways to get the required result! My favorite is

```
x3 <- c(0.0025, seq(0.005, 0.06, by=0.005))
```

because when you read it aloud, you really create a vector for which"*, after the first value 0.0025, the values increase by 0.0025 and then continuously by 0.005.*"

Comment: Or `c(0.0025, 0.005*(1:12))` instead of the `ifelse`

Comment: Or `c(0.0025, seq(0.005, by = 0.005, length = 12)` in case you have the length of the vector rather than it's endpoint.